# レンタルサーバーにおけるドメインの設定に関して。（メールの送受信）

Tags: dns, mail

現在、以下の2つを使用しています。

- レンタルサーバA(さくらサーバースタンダード)
- レンタルサーバB(Xserver)

#### 質問内容要旨

Aサーバに設定してあるドメインを、メールの受け取りと返信だけをBサーバで行いたい。
※ Aサーバに設定してあるWEBページなどはそのままにしておきたい。

#### 状況

Aサーバに設定してあるドメイン（Axample.com）にてメールの受信をしているのですが、自動返信機能が必要になり、
Bサーバにて(Axample.com)宛のメールを送受信することはできないか？と考えています。（Xserverには自動返信設定があるため。）

#### 状況補足

Aサーバにて設定してある広告の都合上（外部業者に委託）、切り替え時にダウンタイムが発生するとなんらかのペナルティが広告媒体者により申し伝えられる可能性があり、現在Aサーバに設定してあるドメイン（Axample.com）がメールやアクセス不可能な時間を発生させないで欲しいとの要望があり、Bサーバにドメインを移管するという方法は断念しました。
※ 現在はGmailにて自動フィルタリングをし、必要なメールに対し手動でテンプレートを返信していますが、作業時間が長いので自動化したい。

以上なんらかアドバイスを頂戴できると助かります。よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: 一応DNSのMXレコードとSPFをきちんとBサーバーのものに指定すれば、お望みのことは実現できるかと思いますが、いかがでしょう。あと、自己責任ですが、さくらのレンタルサーバーでも自動返信する方法はあるようです。

Comment: DNSの管理はどこで行う予定ですか？

Comment: - user29034 ありがとうございます。サーバーの.mailfilterを書き換える方法のことでしょうか？その他ご存知でしたらご教示いただきたく願います！

Comment: - keitaro_so 　user29034 様のご指摘の通りBサーバで行えば良いのかな？と考えておりました。

Comment: @S.Takahashi DNSサーバーの話とAサーバー、Bサーバーの話は別問題ですね。例えば私は DNS はムームードメインで、メールはさくらで、WWW は自宅サーバーで管理しているドメインがあります。

Comment: - hata ありがとうございます。DNSまわりは理解が足りず特にこだわりはないのですが、現在十個ほどのドメインをさくらで管理しています。Xserverも十個くらい顧客のドメインがありますが、特にDNSに関する管理を考えたことはありませんでした。